# Set up source code in NetBeans

Tags: java

I'm new with NetBeans. I already know how to set up JDK source code in Eclipse based on this tutorial [How to attach source code to Eclipse](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-view-and-debug-jdk-source-code-in-eclipse.html)

But is there any way to see the source code to press F3 in NetBeans as we could do in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alt + O should take you to its source

Look here for more netbeans shortcuts.

[Netbeans Shortcuts](https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/www/shortcuts.pdf)